# Android widgets layout setup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my app i have a custom dialog whose layout is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack = "true"    
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="blablabla...."/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:src="@drawable/book1"/>       
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="blablablablablablablablabla..."/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:src="@drawable/book2"/>       
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

That is, i show a list of two horizontally placed widgets: a TextView showing some text and an, adjacent to the text, an ImageView widget showing an image.

What i would like to do is to show the ImageView widgets in such a way that they are aligned, that is, the image 1 start at the same column of image 2.

How can i do that?
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are hoping for, but I would do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blablabla...." />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/book1" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
            android:text="blablablablablablablablabla..." />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/book2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I changed it to a relative layout and used some attributes such as android:layout_below
and android:layout_alignParentRight="true to get these changes.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect thx!! Do you know how to add a separator between the first two  widgets and the second two?

Comment: No, I do not.  My only thought is to add another image to use as a separator.  This has its down falls though, because you are using another resource, which makes file size larger.  Plus, you may not be able to achieve the look you desire.